# Multiple GeoJSON-based maps (Highmaps) on RMarkdown documents

Tags: javascript, r, rcharts, htmlwidgets

I am currently using rCharts/highcharter to draw multiple interactive maps in a Rmarkdown document.

````
```{r, results='asis',echo=F}
cat("#",topics[[1]]$TOPIC_TITLE_DESC[1],"\n")
tagList(lapply(topicList,myFunc))
```
````

But, the HTML page it generates wrapped the GeoJSON files within each map leading to a super large file.

My question is:

It there a way to make the GeoJSON file global (store as a JSON object somewhere in the HTML) so that script can read from it rather than embed it every time?